# nextjs run custom hook/function on startup

Tags: next.js

For some purposes, I need to run console logs when I start nextjs project. for that, I need to. But I couldn't find a method to do it. Does anyone have a solutin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute code on startup by using the `pages/_app.js` file.
Create a file named _app.js inside the pages directory
Inside `_app.js`, import the necessary modules, sUse `useEffect` hook to execute your code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Your custom code to run on startup
    console.log('Next.js application started');
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

edit:

Create a file named server.js in the root directory

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }).listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('Next.js application started');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ADITYA but i meant i need console to be shown on terminal or server-side

Comment: you can use Node.js's built-in console.log function in a custom server script.

(see the edited code now)

Comment: mark the answer as completed, if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a function from `next.config.js` and add your log there. It will run at startup (including on reload, when you save a file on dev mode)

See [next.config.js Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js)

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = async () => {
    console.log('startup')
    return {
        /* config options here */
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```